# Where is TeXworks after installing TeX Live 2011 on Fedora 15?

Tags: texlive, linux

I've installed TeX Live 2011 on Fedora 15 following the guide at the texlive site, http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html. I've got `texdoc`, `tlmgr` and so on working from the terminal but I can't find TeXworks. I'm new to Fedora so this could be a very simple mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, TeX Live doesn't install TeXworks on GNU/Linux systems, because it would be too difficult to cope with dependencies on the various distributions. You can find a packaged version at

https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/applications/Texworks/

Comment: You can also compile from source pretty easily on most Linux platforms

Comment: On Fedora 15 "yum install texworks" will install TeXworks 0.4.3 which is the latest one - and will keep it up-to-date. So no need to install it by hand or by compiling it.